# Are there any equations for the mass of fuel (ejected at some velocity) required to propel a rocket of some mass some distance through gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, conservation-laws, rocket-science

Either through constant gravity, more simply, or through the changing gravitational field, more accurately. This appears to be a fully determined system, although I found no analytic solutions for this problem online. The best I could find was the rocket equation minus gt: $\Delta v = u \cdot ln(\frac{m_i}{m_f}) - g \cdot t_{burn}$, which although nice, absolutely does not solve this particular quandary analytically.

I heard Neil deGrasse Tyson [say](https://youtu.be/-73MZsj8bVI?t=281) the relationship between the nonfuel mass and the fuel mass required to propel it through gravity was exponential, because each new mass of fuel has to propel not just the payload but, itself the new mass of fuel — exponential like the relationship between the desired final/maximum change in velocity in the rocket equation is as a function of the mass ratio, as it can easily be shown to be. Yet I can't find anything that demonstrates this exponentiality between the mass of nonfuel mass of the rocket and the mass of the additional necessary fuel to propel the rocket a given delta distance through earth's gravity.

First of all, is Neil deGrasse Tyson right about this exponential relationship, and is there really no analytic relationship to describe it (which would surprise me)?

Comment: The exponential relationship is literally the equation you wrote in your post.

Comment: @KyleKanos Kyle, I am referring to the exponential relationship between mi and mf over a constant distance when gravity is involved, not the exponential relationship between mi/mf and delta v when gravity is not involved. For example, when gravity is not involved, for a constant deltav and u, the relationship between mi and mf is linear, with a proportionality constant of e^deltav /(e^u). These are different things.

Comment: First, the exponential relationship isn't found from considering a constant distance but a small interval of time, $\Delta t$ (assuming roughly constant velocity would yield same idea though) via momentum conservation. Second, you can easily start with a variable mass system ($F_\text{ext}=v_\text{rel}\dot{m}+m\dot{v}$ and essentially find the same equation when you define $\Delta v_\text{eff}\sim \Delta v_\text{exh}-g\Delta t$. It's basically the same thing. If you mean differnetly, you should edit your post to clarify what you mean.